# How to log error from angular front end to to backend via custom or anything other api to serilogs table Mssqlsink

Tags: angular, logging, serilog

How to log error from angular front end to to backend via custom or anything other api to serilogs table Mssqlsink ? 
As my application has multiple api from different thrid party resources wanted to log the errors from other api consumed in angular to backend api. For backend custom api have used serilog sql sink as logger so wanted to use serilog to log errors received from angular app. 
Can anybody share sample, thank is andvance.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is just setting up a generic text dump API and use that. Always bear in mind that this text dump require no authentication and shall be flood-proof.

What I do: Client:

```
 POST /api/ad-hoc/error-report-dump-endpoint HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.app.com
 X-Error-Name: HttpClientRequestTimeoutError
 X-Error-Severeness: 1

 HttpClientRequestTimeoutError: timeout, lol. at send_request xxxxx.js:14223 .... (dump error.stack here)
```

Server:

```
 const error_logbook = new FIFO<ErrorLogType>()
 error_logbook.maxLength = 30000

 function handle_error_log(r : IncomingCompletedPostRequest) {
    error_logbook.enqueue({time: Date.now(), name:r.headers["X-Error-Name"], stack: r.postbody})
 }
```

Reason I log nothing onto the disk so that whatever naughty boi who found this endpoint cannot flood my storage with garbage. If you do want persistence, you need to implement countermeasures to flood yourself I guess.